# Errors in converting JSON to Map in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am new to scala and I am trying to write a function that takes in a JSON, converts it to Scala dictionary (`Map`) and checks for certain keys

Below is part of a function that checks for a bunch keys

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json
def setParams(jsonString: Map[String, Any]) = {
    val paramsMap = Json.parse(jsonString)
    if (parmsMap.contains("key_1")) {
      println('key_1 present')
    }
```

On compiling it with `sbt`, I get the following errors

```
/Users/usr/scala_codes/src/main/scala/wrapped_code.scala:29:26: overloaded method value parse with alternatives:
[error]   (input: Array[Byte])play.api.libs.json.JsValue <and>
[error]   (input: java.io.InputStream)play.api.libs.json.JsValue <and>
[error]   (input: String)play.api.libs.json.JsValue
[error]  cannot be applied to (Map[String,Any])
[error]     val paramsMap = Json.parse(jsonString)
[error]                          ^
[error] /Users/usr/scala_codes/src/main/scala/wrapped_code.scala:31:9: not found: value parmsMap
[error]     if (parmsMap.contains("key_1")) {
```

Also, in key-value pairs of the JSON, the keys are all strings but the values could be integers, floats or strings. Do I need to make changes for that?

Comment: @andriy-plokhotnyuk would you mind indicatingthat' you're the author when mentioning jsoniter please?

Comment: @andriy-plokhotnyuk It's a rule on SO to indicate that you are part of when suggesting a solution. On the other side "Feel free to skip my comments if your system accepts only trusted input or efficiency is not required." could be understood as there is no other solution than what you mentioned ...

Answer (score 0):

Seems your input type in setParams function should be `String` not `Map[String, Any]`
and you have one typo: `if (parmsMap.contains("key_1"))` should be `if (paramsMap.contains("key_1"))`
correct function:

```
def setParams(jsonString: String): Unit = {
  val paramsMap = Json.parse(jsonString).as[Map[String, JsValue]]
  if (paramsMap.contains("key_1")) println('key_1 present')
}
```